# Display some simple data in HTML

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, spring

`activeUsers.getUsers()` returns a list with the online users in my app.

I want to display it in my HTML but I have no idea how to do this. I'm getting error 404 on my ajax request yet if I put a breakpoint in my controller it shows the list of online users.

Any help??

Controller

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/loggedUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getLoggedUsers(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("loggedUsers", activeUsers.getUsers());
    return "loggedUsers";
}
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//get loggedUsers
$.ajax({
    url: '/loggedUsers',
    type: 'get',
    success: function (loggedUsers) {
        console.log(loggedUsers);
    }
});
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="sidebar-right" class="visible">
<ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li id="dashboard">
        <a href="dashboard">
            <c:forEach var="loggedUser" items="${loggedUsers}">
                <span class="menu-title">${loggedUser}</span>
            </c:forEach>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the console log returns:

> error 404

Comment: the ajax returns 404 but it's calling the function

Comment: You aren't returning the list of users but a view. The `loggedUsers.jsp` (or whatever view technology you use cannot be found). Instead just return the list of users and annotate the method with `@responseBody` that way you get the list of users as JSON and then user some JS to render the list.

Comment: you are right. thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller and add `@ResponseBody` annotation above it. Your code should look like

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/loggedUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  @ResponseBody
  public String getLoggedUsers(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("loggedUsers", activeUsers.getUsers());
  return "loggedUsers";
}
```

This will return only the content and won't look for `jsp` for example. (the reason you got `404`)

Comment: but I still need to append it dynamically with jquery? Is there a way to put the loggedUsers already in the html?

Comment: are you building rest API ? what's the name of your html file ?

Comment: I don't know if it's REST or not. It's a website with Spring MVC5. The page is called`sidebar-right.jsp` and I include in every page using `<%@include file="sidebar-right.jsp"%>`

Comment: well, I would seriously suggest you to have a look at this https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/

Comment: This will give you complete idea of how to follow spring guidelines to build spring based apps

Answer (score 1):

Add `@Response` body. You need to make this a REST API because it's a AJAX call.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/loggedUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public @ResponseBody String getLoggedUsers(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("loggedUsers", activeUsers.getUsers());
  return "loggedUsers";
}
```